# iOS game Development with Swift. SKScene/SprikeKit changes?

Tags: ios, swift, skscene

I'm new to iOS game development, I've been following this tutorial series and if someone doesn't mind taking a peek at this video(near the end) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s0hRlSlT6Zw&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGDgp7nGSUnnXihbTLFZJ79B&index=34 I've copied the entire code but if you look at the touchesBegan function it seems the newer versions of swift have a different function than his,

Here's how his reads

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set NSSet, withEvent event:UIEvent) {

let introLabel = childNodeWithName("introLabel")

if(introLabel != nil) {
    let fadeOut = SKAction.fadeOutWithDuration(1.5)

    introLabel?.runAction(fadeOut, completion: {
        let doors = SKTransition.doorwayWithDuration(1.5)
        let shooterScene = ShooterScene(fileNamed: "ShooterScene")
        self.view?.presentScene(shooterScene, transition: doors)
    })
}
```

}

mine reads

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    let introLabel = childNodeWithName("introLabel")

    if(introLabel != nil) {
        let fadeOut = SKAction.fadeOutWithDuration(1.5)

        introLabel?.runAction(fadeOut, completion: {
            let doors = SKTransition.doorwayWithDuration(1.5)
            let shooterScene = ShooterScene(fileNamed: "ShooterScene")
            self.view?.presentScene(shooterScene, transition: doors)
        })
    }

}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
}
```

GameViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {
        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
}

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
        return .AllButUpsideDown
    } else {
        return .All
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
```

everything written in that method is the same but I'm getting an error unless i put a ! after shooterScene in the line self.view?.presentScene(shooterScene, transition: doors)

Regardless whether or not I add the ! when I click on the screen the transition doesn't occur. Can someone offer a solution?

Comment: Please add the whole code of the scene, nobody wants to look through a video and copy code in order to try and simulate your problem.

Comment: By more code I meant the whole view controllers so that it is easy to simulate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because no touch is ever detected. What you need is:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>?, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch: AnyObject in touches! {

        let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)

        button.containsPoint(touchLocation) {
            //Button pressed; move to next scene
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code that works for me.